Question about waves in a fixed string
consider a string that is fixed at both ends. This string is connected to a metal stick. When I hit the metal stick, sound waves (longitudinal and transversal ?) will propagate trough the metal and finally also through the string. My question now is: If the the frequency of the vibration does not match the eigenfrequency of the string, there should be no forming of standing waves. But can the waves that are forming be described as the superposition of standing waves?

Yes, they can. The waves in the metal rod will enter the region of the string, and the wave you conveyed to the metal rod will give place to a superposition of infinite harmonics of the string. You can easily decompose the wave in the rod using a Fourier series. A more detailed analysis would involve analyzing reflections where the two media coincide.

The overall system can be modeled as a linear mechanical systems whose governing equations, after discretization,
$$\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r},t) = \sum_{i=1}^N \phi_i(\mathbf{r}) u_i(t) = \phi'(\mathbf{r}) u(t) \ ,$$
can be recast as a mass-sping $N$-dimenisonal system
$$M \, \ddot{u} + K \, u = f \ ,$$
being $M$ and $K$ the mass and stiffness matrices of the problem, and $u$ the vector of the amplitudes of the base functions used for the discretization.
What you call "standing-waves" are the modes of the mechanical system. It's well known that the mechanical system described by the equation above with no free-motion has definite positive mass and stiffness matrix and a set of orthogonal eigenvectors $u_k$ (w.r.t the inner product involving matrix or stiffness matrices, i.e. $u_k' M u_i = m \delta_{ki}$) that can be collected in the matrix $U$. The variable $u(t)$ can be written in this basis as
$$u(t) = U q(t) \ ,$$
with $q(t)$ the vector containing the modal amplitudes. Multiplying by $U'$ the governing equation, and using the modal variables, the governing equation becomes a diagonal system, i.e. the dynamical equations of modes (amplitude standing waves) are independent,
$$U' M U \ddot{q} + U' K U q(t) = U' f(t) \quad \rightarrow \quad m_k \ddot{q}_k(t) + k_k q_k(t) = U_{ik} f_i(t) \ .$$
Know, if you know the forcing of the system and the initial conditions (here assumed to be homogeneous (i.e. system at rest), you can solve this equation, either in time domain or in the most suitable transformed domain, usually Fourier for periodic or stochastic signals, Laplace for compact ones.
As an example, assuming $f_i(t)$ is a impulsive force that can be written as $F_i \delta(t)$, being $F_i$ the "shape" of the impulsive force in the "nodal" degrees of freedom $u$, the equation in the Laplace domain reads,
$$\left( s^2 + \omega_k^2 \right) \hat{q}_k = U_{ik} F_i = \tilde{F}_k \ ,$$
whose solution in the Laplace domain is
$$\hat{q}_k = \frac{1}{s^2 + \omega_k^2} \tilde{F}_k = \frac{i}{2 \omega_k} \left( \frac{1}{s+i\omega_k}  - \frac{1}{s-i\omega_k} \right) \tilde{F}_{k}\ ,$$
whose anti-transform reads (using $\mathscr{L}(e^{at})(s) = \frac{1}{s-a}$)
$$q_k(t) = - \frac{\tilde{F}_k}{\omega_k} \frac{1}{2i} \left( e^{-i\omega_k t} - e^{i \omega_k t} \right) = \frac{\tilde{F}_k}{\omega_k} \sin \left(\omega_k t\right) = \frac{U_{ik} F_i}{\omega_k} \sin \left(\omega_k t\right) \ ,$$
give you the amplitude of the $k^{th}$ mode (standing wave) as a function of time.
Once found the amplitudes of the modes, you can go back into the process to find:

the amplitudes of the nodal variables $u(t)$
$$u_i(t) = U_{ik} q_k(t) = \frac{U_{ik} U_{\ell k} F_\ell}{\omega_k} \sin \left(\omega_k t\right)$$

the continuous solution $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r},t)$,
$$\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r},t) = \sum_{i=1}^N \phi_i(\mathbf{r}) u_i(t) = \sum_{i=1}^N \phi_i(\mathbf{r}) \frac{U_{ik} U_{\ell k} F_\ell}{\omega_k} \sin \left(\omega_k t\right) \ . $$


